# Handling custom javascript exceptions in iOS's UIAutomation UIATarget.onAlert

Tags: javascript, ios, scope, integration-testing, ios-ui-automation

I've set up some UIAutomation scripts that will eventually become jenkins tests. The UIAutomation scripts do not output in jenkins-friendly format, so I'm using [tuneup_js](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js), specifically this [failure exception](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js/blob/master/assertions.js#L6).

When a test fails, I can throw a custom `FailureException`. The exception is gracefully caught and failure output is properly logged. The output is `Error: FailureException: "hello world"`.

My problem occurs when I try to throw that same `FailureException` inside an `onAlert` handler, `UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {...}`. In my `onAlert` function, I throw a `FailureException` if the title matches a certain regex, but the `FailureException` is never caught and the tests crash with the following output:

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: hello world on line 18 of assertions.js
```

Any ideas how I can throw this `FailureException` inside the `onAlert` handler and handle it properly? It seems as if the `onAlert` is handled in a different scope than the rest of the tests, but I'm not sure how to rectify that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core problem here is that js exceptions don't really work with asynchronous code like an event loop (which is why you rarely see thrown exceptions at all in "modern javascript" code and people use error callbacks instead).

If you look at the `test` function in tuneup_js, it catches an exception that gets thrown by `fail` and then calls `UIALogger.logFail`.  `UIATarget.onAlert` will respond to some top-level alert event and run in that context, outside of the test function, so triggering an exception there means it won't be caught by the try/catch block in `test`.

One thing that does work is is using a closure to return data to the caller, something like:

```
test("My UI Test", function(app, target) {
    var failureName = null;
    setupOnAlert(function(name) {
        failureName = name;
    });
    // do something that might trigger a UIAlert
    if (failureName) {
        fail(failureName);
    }
});

function setupOnAlert(fail_callback) {
UITarget.onAlert = function(alert) {
    // do something that may fail, if it fails:
    fail_callback("Some kind of error");
}
}
```

Hope that helps!